# Javascript replace window.open with an onload function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that opens a login.htm window in the mode I would like after I click a button on my index.htm page ....

```
function openApp()  {
    var options = "channelmode=" + 1 +
        ",resizable=" + 1 +
        ",menubar=" + 0 + 
        ",toolbar=" + 0 + 
        ",location=" + 0 + 
        ",titlebar=" + 1 +
        ",status=" + 1 +
        ",scrollbars=" + 1;

    var name = "reporting";
    var appURL = "login.htm"
    var newWindow = window.open(appURL,name,options);   
    newWindow.focus();
}
```

It works fine but now I would like to move the functionality of opening the window into the login.htm window on load function.

For example if someone goes to login.htm itself, i want the window to open up in that mode.

I've tried a few things but can't figure this out. Can someone please help me.

I am using jquery so I could do it using jquery.

thanks

Comment: What functionality are you talking about?

Comment: in my onload function I want to set all the options that i was previously doing with var options. The options specified do cool things like maximise the window and disable the navigation bar. SO want to keep them but just set them in the load function if i can do that

Answer (score 0):

You would take the section that `var options` is being set and put it outside of the `openApp()` function, like so:

```
var options = "channelmode=" + 1 +
    ",resizable=" + 1 +
    ",menubar=" + 0 + 
    ",toolbar=" + 0 + 
    ",location=" + 0 + 
    ",titlebar=" + 1 +
    ",status=" + 1 +
    ",scrollbars=" + 1;

function openApp()  {
    var name = "reporting";
    var appURL = "login.htm"
    var newWindow = window.open(appURL,name,options);   
    newWindow.focus();
}
```

Then you can call `openApp()` however you'd like.

If you want to run `openApp()` to execute when the whole page is fully loaded (i.e. all images are loaded) then you'd do the following:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  openApp();
});
```

If you want to execute `openApp()` when the document is in its "ready" state (when he DOM is available to manipulate), then do the following:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  openApp();
});
```

Comment: But if I just run the function it will open a new window. What I want in the login.htm on load function is to set all the options (var options) that I was previously doing using window.open. Does that make sense

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following what you mean when you say you want to "set all the options (var options) that I was previously doing using window.open". Do you mind further clarifying?

Comment: so in my post there is a variable named options. It is being passed into window.open function. Those options give the new window a look and feel. At the moment I am running that openApp from the index.jsp page. What I want to do is change my app not to use index.jsp and allow my users to go directly to login.htm. But when my users go to login.htm how do I initialise that window with the same look and feel properties

Comment: OK, trying to re-understand your issue, I've modified my proposed solution above. Hopefully it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a DOM element with a click event that opens the login.htm and you want to open a new window as well with the same window properties if another DOM element is clicked just set the click event to that that DOM element, as in `<span onclick="openApp()">Login</span>`.

You could navigate to the log in page and set a setTimeout.

Just place this code in the log in page that the user navigates to, and it will open a new window on its own after the log in page DOM is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    setTimeout(function () {

        var openApp = function () {

            var options = "channelmode=" + 1 +
                ",resizable=" + 1 +
                ",menubar=" + 0 +
                ",toolbar=" + 0 +
                ",location=" + 0 +
                ",titlebar=" + 1 +
                ",status=" + 1 +
                ",scrollbars=" + 1;

            var name = "reporting",
                appURL = "login.htm",
                newWindow = window.open(appURL, name, options);

            newWindow.focus();
        }();

    }, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: no sorry. You have misunderstood my requirement. I must not have explained properly. Can you please have a look at the last comment I added to jonsuh. This might help